# How can i check user and password with php and ajax

Tags: php, ajax, validation

I have doubts on how to check the name and password of users, which are stored in an array, I do not know how to do it with ajax

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="tuser" /><br>
<input type="password" id="password" /><br>
<input type="submit" id="send" value="Send"/><br>
<input type="range" id="rg" name="rg" min="0" max="50"/><br>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#tuser").focus();$("#rg").hide();

        });     
        $("#tuser").keyup(function() {
            $.ajax({type:"GET",
                url: "validate.php",
                data:"names="+$("#tuser").val()+"pass="+$("#password").val(),
                success:function(data) {
                    if (data=="Error") {
                        $("rango").hide();
                    } else {
                        $("#rg").show();

                    }
                }
            });
        });
</script>
```

PHP Validate  (here I Know how to send the name but i dont know how to send the password)

```
if($_GET['names']!=''){
  $personal=array("Kaoru"=>'hello1',"Megumi"=>'hello2',"Naoko"=>'hello3');
  foreach ($personal as $key=>$value){

      if(isset($personal['$key'])&& $personal['$key']=='$value') {
      echo $apersonal[$_GET['names']];
  } else {
      print "Error";


}}}?>
```

Thanks in advancessssssssss

Comment: Well, don't send it `GET` (use `POST` so errors and exceptions don't get logged with the username/password in plaintext), and **ensure** it is transported with HTTPS, not HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({type:"POST",   
data:"names="+$("#tuser").val()+"&pass="+$("#password").val(),

if( isset($_POST['names']) && !is_empty($_POST['names']) ){
  $personal=array("Kaoru"=>'hello1',"Megumi"=>'hello2',"Naoko"=>'hello3');      

      if(isset($personal[$_POST['names']])&& $personal[ $_POST['names'] ] == $_POST['pass']) {
        echo "Logged IN";
      }else{
         echo "Wrong user or pass";
      }

  } else {
      print "Error";


}
```

Comment: You don't use `GET` for passwords, always use `POST` (for both).

Comment: get / post, does not matter for security or so.

Comment: Excuse me? Where did you hear that?

Comment: Uh.. ya it does.  Never use `GET` for passwords.